# Android: how to parse a BIG JSON stream

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON stream with Android to put all the elements as Markers in an **ActivityMap**.

The problem is the quantity of the data: **json returns over 3300 rows of a mysql db**, and every row has 3 objects. So when i try to fetch all the data with an async task the system after a while returns Application Not Responding.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Service`. You can find tutorial in [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Services is mostly using for big data transfer ,also regular methods for example connect server per 2 hours. Services working on background and user can't see , because services doesnt include a layout only work on background. you can set your service self destroy when your work finish.Just trigger your `Service` ,connect your stream and handle your big response . When finish self destroy your service.

Comment: I've tried something these days, but the problem persist also with a service. The application goes to ANR while it tries to create the JSON Object from the string that it get from server. As @Marzouk said, maybe I have to do more than one call to server to fetch json data

Comment: You can use paging method. For example return 20 object and next page url from json , this is one deal . Also you can use Gson check below comment. Just create POJO class here : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
But best way is using paging method in your server. Just return nextpageurl field. If equals na or null stop your requests but equals any string create new request and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the parsing in a service not in your application Activities.

Also you can separate a call for a smaller calls for example get every 1000 row in a separate AsyncTask but it's not a better solution in a performance wise, I think the better way is to use services or loaders instead of the traditional AsyncTask way that it's have a big couple with the activity it self.

Loaders:[loaders-and-loadermanager](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)

Services:[android_services](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)

Also check your server side timeout config, it may be due a timeout from server side.

Comment: I think that I have to do more than one call so I can use smaller json object.. Later I will try :)

Comment: Also check your server side timeout config, it may be due a timeout from server side.

Answer (score -1):

If you have json data, and corresponding Model class, and you want to map json data to Model class, I would recommend using Gson() library. It will parse your json data to your java class. Include following line to your gradle dependencies in order to include Gson() library.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

Check below links that will give you further idea of using this library.

[Link1](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)  and [Link2](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-gson-to-work-with-json-in-your-android-apps/)